# Best way to check for updated rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, comparison, timestamp

I am trying to see if there were any rows updated since the last time it was checked.
I'd like to know if there are any better alternatives to

```
"SELECT id FROM xxx WHERE changed > some_timestamp;"
```

However, as there are 200,000+ rows it can get heavy pretty fast... would a count be any better?

```
"SELECT count(*) FROM xxx WHERE changed > some_timestamp;"
```

I have thought of creating a unit test but I am not the best at this yet /:

Thanks for the help!

---

EDIT: Because in many cases there would not be any rows that changed, would it be better to always test with a MAX(xx) first, and if its greater than the old update timestamp given, then do a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know if *any* rows have changed, the following query is probably faster than either of yours:

```
SELECT id FROM xxx WHERE changed > some_timestamp LIMIT 1
```

Just for the sake of completeness: Make sure you have an index on `changed`.

**Edit: A tiny performance improvement**

Now that I think about it, you should probably do a `SELECT change` instead of selecing the `id`, because that eliminates accessing the table *at all*. This query will tell you pretty quickly if any change was performed.

```
SELECT changed FROM xxx WHERE changed > some_timestamp LIMIT 1
```

It should be a tiny bit faster than my first query - not by a lot, though, since accessing a single table row is going to be very fast.

**Should I select `MAX(changed)` instead?**

Selecting `MAX(changed)`, as suggested by Federico should pretty much result in the same index access pattern. Finding the highest element in an index is a very cheap operation. Finding any element that is greater than some constant is potentially cheaper, so both should have approximately the same performance. In either case, both queries are extremely fast even on very large tables if - and only if - there is an index.

**Should I first check if any rows were changed, and then retrieve the rows in a separate step**

No. If there is no row that has changed, `SELECT id FROM xxx WHERE changed > some_timestamp` will be *as fast as* any such check making it pointless to perform it separately. It only turns into a slower operation when there are results. Unless you add expensive operations (such as `ORDER BY`), the performance should be (almost) linear to the number of rows retrieved.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, can you check my EDIT and see if this is still valid?

Answer (score 1):

Make an index on some_timestamp and run:

```
SELECT MAX(some_timestamp) FROM xxx;
```

If the table is MyISAM, the query will be immediate.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, can you check my EDIT and see if this is still valid?

Comment: Hi! If you use MyISAM, finding max/min value of an index is always the cheapest operation. In case of InnoDB... I'm sure that there is not a noticeable difference, but the equivalent of MAX is not what you written, it's: SELECT val FROM tab ORDER BY val DESC LIMIT 1